# Creating functions for re-usable features in karate-core

Tags: karate

I built a framework on top of Karate and have several reusable functions (mostly Javascript and utilities). We can reuse features but I was wondering whether there's a way to wrap the call to those features using a Javascript function for UI functions. I think it makes it easier to the tests to abstract some of this code - almost like extending the DSL with some custom functions.

I seem to be able to achieve this with functions from the Karate DSL which are not part of the UI automation packages / [karate-core](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core) but not for UI functions.

For example I have the following reusable feature named *click.feature* (workaround for clickable "divs" in which .click() doesn't seem to work in Web Driver):

```
Scenario:
  Then def pos = position(__arg.selector)
  And def x = Math.round(pos.x + pos.width/2)
  And def y = Math.round(pos.y + pos.height/2)
  And mouse().move(x, y).click()
```

And the following JS function:

```
Scenario:    
  * def moveAndClick =
  """
    function(selector) {
      karate.call('click.feature', ( { selector : selector } ))
    }
  """
```

When I try to use it I get the following error:

```
click.feature:5 - evaluation (js) failed: position(__arg.selector), javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "position" is not defined in <eval> at line number 1
```

This seems to be limited to the UI functions as I tried the *assert* or *print* keywords and those work. Am I missing something or is this by design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check this issue and see if that addresses your problem: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1280 - would be great if you can build from source and verify: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/Developer-Guide

So by default, the `driver` object is not defined until the point you invoke a URL for the first time. But if you want to use re-usable functions, they have to use `karate.get('driver')`, and then you can use that to chain functions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Peter. Using the code from the develop branch I tried using the `karate.get('driver')` inside the shared feature that I'm invoking over JS but the result is null.

Defining the variable and pass it as parameter to the function  I get the following error:

`test-karate.feature:29 - evaluation (js) failed: helper.moveAndClick(loginScreen.submitButton, driverVar), java.lang.RuntimeException: no Getter for field windowState in class com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.Chrome`

Comment: @jramos okay. I saw your comment on the git issue also thanks, we can continue the discussion there

Comment: I can confirm this is resolved with the fix identified on that github issue